# Gradle selective dependency in parent build

Tags: gradle

I have this project structure:

```
parent/
    build.gradle
    settings.gradle
    child1/
        build.gradle
    child2/
        build.gradle
    child3/
        build.gradle
```

I have a dependency dep1 that is shared between child1 and child2 but not child3. Is there a way to define a

```
dependencies
{
    compile dep1
}
```

in the parent build.gradle, but tell it to apply to only child1 and child2?

Or do I have to define this dependency in each of child1 and child2's build.gradle files, so it does not show in child3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is

```
configure(subprojects.findAll {it.name != 'child3'}) {
    dependencies {
        // dep1
    }
}
```

You can see find more about your sub-project configuration options in Gradle User Guild [**here**](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html).